# Dots on Shading Viewer

Tags: modeling, particles, shaders

how do i get rid all of these small black dots on my shading viewer? Its so annoying.

[image: ShadingDots]

Comment: Looks like it's a GPU issue. Make sure your graphics driver's are up to date.

Comment: Ahh, thats why theres none question regarding this problem. I'm now using old computer for learning process and i'm not sure if it have GPU in it. Anyway, thanks!